# Show component show's all course in courses table from a certain slug or Id

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, slug, livewires

Am trying to show a particular slug or Id from my show-component.blade, but instead it shows all the slugs/Id's in the table.

My ShowComponent

```
    class ShowComponent extends Component
{
    public $slug;

    public function mount($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $course = Course::where('slug',$this->slug)->first();
        return view('livewire.show-component',['course'=>$course]);
    }
}
```

Curriculum's table

```
public function grade() {
    return $this->hasMany(Grade::class);
}


Grade's table

protected $primaryKey = 'id';

public function curricula() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Curriculum::class);
}
```

and Courses table

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

// A product Grade belongs to a product
public function grade() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class);
}
```

Comment: What does the table look like and how do you render this?

Comment: The app has Curriculum, Grade, and course table, and the are related using laravel eloquent

Comment: Please show the relevant code, or it'll be hard for others to assist you